Are you "allowed" to go to a football game as a fan of a third team?
Away fans wrong ending is common. You see a lot of questions around the Internet asking about doing this. Officially it's completely forbidden but general advice is just be subtle about it and many manage to do it (though there was a recent case where a team cancelled a ticket booked in this way due to social media).
When you go to book a ticket for most (all?) teams' home end, the terms and conditions make clear that by doing so, you confirm you're a fan of that team.
So... where does leave people who are neither home nor away fans?
I'm considering both complete neutrals who just want to see a game, and fans of the away team's rival who don't normally care about the home team, but they're in the area and why not support them.
Would there ever be any trouble in these situations?
Of course, you can keep your head down quite easily, even in the wrong end.
But officially, if it's obvious a supporter is absolutely not a fan of the home team (e.g. they show up to Man City vs. Leicester in a Man Utd shirt), are they allowed in? What's the official word on this?

Regarding the "show up in a Man Utd shirt" example: https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/9217/15589

There is no allowed or forbidden in general. Every club has its own rules. In the Bundesliga it is common practice to not wear the team colors of the opponent or any rival. Others are ok.

That's unusual (for me)! Here in America (especially in places with generally unpopular teams) there's absolutely no rules against showing up supporting the other team. I can confirm this for fact (baseball, but relevant IMO) because I have vivid memories of a couple of drunken Rockies fans being loud and obnoxious towards the D-Backs a few years back and nobody said anything. They did get kicked out, if memory serves, for starting a fight, but that had nothing to do with the fact that they showed up wearing purple. Maybe futbol culture is different? Maybe I'm just a crazy Westerner?

@AustinOverton yes, football fans are different. Especially in Europe, rivalries are a major part of fan culture and there are not only the positive perks. You won't come far with a blue kit in Dortmund for example. They don't just despise their rivals (Schalke 04), but many of them really hate them and their fans. I've never seen that in any other sport. And I also follow Rhein Fire in the ELF (American football). This is an entirely different world.

@dly Just as I thought, it's a culture thing. I sort of expected this kind of reply which is why I added the "...I'm just the weird westerner" thing at the end, which was partly joking, but mostly serious. I count this as my "learn something new every day" for today.
